# 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WheelEvent<Element>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to find out what's the correct `type` for the event on an a window scroll listener, I cannot find any reference to fix this error, I see people just assigning the type `any`

```
const handleNavigation = (e: React.WheelEvent) => {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling down')
  } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up')
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', e => handleNavigation(e))
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', e => handleNavigation(e))
}, [])
```

TypeScript errors out on the `e` parameter on the event listener

```
`Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WheelEvent<Element>'`
```

Comment: Side Note 1: Your `removeEventListener` code won't work because you're not passing the **same** function to it that you passed to `addEventListener` (because you're wrapping `handleNavigation` in an arrow function in each place). Side Note 2: You don't need the arrow functions, just `.addEventListener(handleNavigation)` and `.removeEventListener(handleNavigation)` (which, conveniently, solves the issue in Side Note #1 :-) ). None of which solves the type problem you've asked about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [`WheelEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent) is for the [`wheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event), not the [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event). If you want `deltaY`, you want the `wheel` event. If you use that, the types work. Here"s an example (with the arrow functions removed per my comment on the question):

```typescript
const handleNavigation = (e: WheelEvent) => { // *** Declare with the DOM"s `WheelEvent` type (not `React.WheelEvent`)
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        console.log("scrolling down");
    } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        console.log("scrolling up");
    }  
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);                 // *** Use `wheel`
    return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation); // *** Use `wheel`
}, []);
```

Comment: I did have the guard and TypeScript complained with all that, but I do have a pretty strict TypeScript set up

Comment: @Álvaro - Fixed it. Sorry about that. I really should trust React. :-)

Comment: Thank you, that simplifies things quite a bit, although it does limit the event to the mouse wheel and will not trigger on bar scroll

Comment: @Álvaro - Right - for that you'd need the `scroll` event and to track the `scrollY` of the container yourself to get the delta/direction.

Comment: I have a similar issue. When I use the solution presented above, I got `Argument of type '(event: WheelEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLDivElement, ev: WheelEvent) => any'.`

Comment: @MWB - This is one of those areas that I find confusing. There are two different `WheelEvent`s: The DOM's (which you use with `addEventListener`) and React's (which you use with `onWheel` props). If you don't import `WheelEvent` from `"react"`, you're using the DOM interface, which is the one you use with `addEventListener`. If you do import it, you're using React's, which you use with `onWheel`. [Here's an example using React's](https://tsplay.dev/N54jow), and [one using the DOM's](https://tsplay.dev/m0oOrN). If that doesn't help, can you show the problem you're having on ...

Comment: ...[the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)? (You can get a URL to share by clicking Share, and you can shorten it to fit in a comment using https://tsplay.dev/.) I'd like to help if I can.

Comment: I was using the autocomplete of Visual Studio Code. As a result, the React `WheelEvent` got imported! Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

DOM methond `window.addEventListener` expects a DOM-EventListener

```
const handleNavigation = (e: Event) => {
   console.log(e.target)
}
```

Comment: If I add `Event` as type then it errors out with `Property 'deltaY' does not exist on type 'Event'`

Answer (score 0):

This kinda had me pulling my hair lately so here's the official way, as it currently stands

```
interface WheelEvent<T = Element> extends MouseEvent<T, NativeWheelEvent> {
    deltaMode: number;
    deltaX: number;
    deltaY: number;
    deltaZ: number;
}

import React, { WheelEvent } from 'react';

const handleWheelEvent = (e: WheelEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    // Do something, e.g. e.deltaY ...
};


<div onWheel={handleWheelEvent}>{/** Some code */}</div>;
```

source https://felixgerschau.com/react-typescript-onwheel-event-type/